# Flutter How do I unselect a previously selected item in a dropdown menu

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, menu, dropdown

I have code that displays a list of items to select.  It correctly lets me type in and search for an item.  But once I select the item, is there a way I can either clear it out as though it were never selected or unselect it.

I can blank out the text box for typing in a menu item.  It then shows as though the item were never selected, but my code never gets notified of a selection, so I still think the original item is selected.  So the next time I draw the screen, that item comes back.

Here is how I'm doing it

```
// pulldown of all crew members that can be selected
class SelectCrewMember extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const SelectCrewMember(this.index, {super.key});

  @override
  State<SelectCrewMember> createState() => _SelectCrewMemberState();
}

class _SelectCrewMemberState extends State<SelectCrewMember> {
  CrewMember? dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final position = CheckinData().getPositionToFill(widget.index);

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 8, 20, 8),
      child: DropdownMenu<CrewMember>(
        enableFilter: true,
        menuHeight: 300,
        width: 300,
        initialSelection: position.member,
        label: Text(position.position.name),
        onSelected: (CrewMember? value) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = value!;
            CheckinData().updateCrew(value, widget.index);
          });
        },
        dropdownMenuEntries: CheckinData()
            .getCrewToPickFrom(widget.index)
            .map<DropdownMenuEntry<CrewMember>>((CrewMember value) {
          return DropdownMenuEntry<CrewMember>(
            value: value,
            label: value.name,
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No way, You can play a trick. Make your first or last item of list (Nothing/-----/Select an Item) like this. If someone makes a mistake, they'll select this one next

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, since I don't think there is a built-in way of doing it.  I added this property to the DropdownMenu widget:

```
trailingIcon: IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
  onPressed: () => CheckinData().updateCrew(null, widget.index),
),
```